# Merge Join results in one array

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.id, u.name, c.category')
        ->innerJoin('u.categories', 'c')
        ->where('u.id = (:user)')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

And I always get this result:

```
Array[0] = 'id' -> 1, 'name' -> john, 'category' -> A
Array[1] = 'id' -> 1, 'name' -> john, 'category' -> B
Array[2] = 'id' -> 1, 'name' -> john, 'category' -> C
```

And I want to get this:

```
Array[0] = 'id' -> 1, 'name' -> john, 'category' -> [A,B,C]
```

If I use Group By u.id I onle get the first Array[0] with first category and I lost the other two categories.

How can I do this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT
    id
  , name
  , GROUP_CONCAT(category) AS categories
FROM
  [table]
GROUP BY
    id
  , name
```

**Doctrine code**

The doctrine code should be something like this.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.id, u.name', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(category) AS categories'))
        ->innerJoin('u.categories', 'c')
        ->where('u.id = (:user)')
        ->groupBy('u.id', 'u.name')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine :)
One more thing, I get 'categories' -> [cat A, cat B...] would be possible to get something like: 'categories' -> [array(catA, catB)] Because in that way I could get separatly these categories.

Comment: @user3396420 it is possible but not with doctrine.. You need to loop the results and use the function explode with delimiter ',' on the categories to create a array.. and save that output somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

See [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in the MySql manual.

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category SEPARATOR ',')
       FROM table_name u
       INNER JOIN categories table c ON (your conditions)
       WHERE u.id = ($user)
       GROUP BY c.category";

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->createQuery($sql);
$em->execute();
```